# I'm trying to install postgresql on 12.04, and it's just not working

Tags: apt, postgresql

I've got a new installation and I'm trying to get Postgresql working.

The database was installed and I started a restoration from a dump on another machine, but that ran into problems because I had forgotten to install the "contrib" package. I used "pg_dropcluster" to drop the old cluster so I could start from scratch, and that's when things went weird.

The first manifestation of this was that /etc/postgresql was just empty. I uninstalled the postgresql package and reinstalled, several times, to no avail.

Is there something I can do to figure out why apt is confused here?  I've done this many times on many systems and never seen anything like this happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I purged it, as well as the "common" package, and it's better now.

Seems like it'd be kind-of nice if it wouldn't get hosed like that.

*edit* that is:

- `apt-get purge postgresql postgresql-common postgresql-9.1 postgresql-contrib-9.1`
- `apt-get -f install`
- `apt-get autoremove`
- `apt-get install postgresql postgresql-common postgresql-9.1 postgresql-contrib-9.1`

and then it worked.